# raid scrub for hp dynamic smart arrays

Tags: hp-smart-array

I'm new to hp servers. we own an hp dl160 gen9 with soft raid. it uses the b140i controller to manage 4 LFF in raid 5.

My question is: how can I scrub the raid? I've installed the hpssacli utils: while they allow me to have a report on the controller and array status, I can not find any reference to data scrubbing.

In linux soft raid I was used to program a periodic check of raid data, I would like to reproduce the same on this server.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The controller handles this in the background.

http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00687518

This is also a feature of the fakeraid Dynamic Smart Areay controllers.

http://m.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04390743.pdf

> Smart Array controllers perform a background surface analysis during
>   inactive periods, continually scanning all drives for media defects.
>   Smart Array controllers can also detect media defects when accessing a
>   bad sector during busy periods. If a Smart Array controller finds a
>   recoverable media defect, the controller automatically remaps the bad
>   sector to a reserve area on the disk drive. If the controller finds an
>   unrecoverable media defect and you have configured a fault-tolerant
>   logical drive, the controller automatically regenerates the data and
>   writes it to the remapped reserved area on the disk drive.

Comment: while it is not so obvious to me reading the docs, I suppose that what you cited is also true for _soft_ raid. The documentation is about Smart Array in general and also provides info about battery backed raids, which is not the case at all for soft raid B1**i controllers! soft raid is just a possible feature in a small paragraph. Thank for the doc's link

Comment: This feature, surface scan analysis, is also present in the dynamic smart array. It's in the specifications. See: http://m.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04390743.pdf